# Приоритет окна в PyQt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, pyqt, qdialog

Допустим у меня есть несколько форм :

1. Главная;
2. Диалог.

Как мне сделать так, чтобы когда у меня был открыт диалог, я не мог взаимодействовать с главной формой?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> int QDialog::exec()
>
> Показывает диалог как модальный диалог, блокируя, пока пользователь не закроет его. Функция возвращает результат DialogCode.

Пример смотрите здесь: [PyQt5 обращение к другой форме](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1102756/pyqt5-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%ba-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%84%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d0%b5)

Вот так:

```
self.dialog.exec_()
```

Comment: Да, я тогда не смог запустить при помощи exec_(), не указал QDialofg вместо QWidget. Сейчас пофиксил. Спасибо

Comment: @FOX_i_K   `QDialog::exec()` - это виртуальный слот `QDialog Class` https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdialog.html#exec